# Do not use quotes in php variables

Tags: apache, xampp, php, ini

In my xampp it returns the following error, when i call functions without quotes (`$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]`)

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant SERVER_NAME - assumed 'SERVER_NAME'
```

What i must change in php.ini to correct this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
:) Sure i know, that if i add quotes, it will work, but i need to configure server to work without quotes too.

I clearly specify my problem. In my server it returns no warnings and no errors, if i do not use quotes. It is depend on xampp version. Now i install newer version of xampp on my local machine, and it show that notices, so i can't use my last projects, because there are handreds of that notices. (it returns such notice even when i use my defined variables, for example  `$myVariable[myItem]`).

i can use

```
error_reporting(0)
```

But that will hide all errors. So i need to just specify new rules for my server, or use older version.

---

### So, Why the downvotes?

---

Comment: Constants exist for a reason and the fact that PHP tells you when you reference one that hasn't been defined yet is a GOOD thing. It helps prevent misspellings, etc so you can catch bugs early on. You're basically trying to tell your server to ignore PHP's correct response. The alternative is to just define them as constants or set your error reporting to ignore notices.

Comment: The syntax without key quotes is only valid in double quote string context.

Comment: I'd say it always valid, considering it's a feature of php. An error prone feature, but a feature for sure. Otherwise undefined constant would be like an undefined variable, type null. It's not.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your php.ini to disable reporting of notices. find your php.ini by doing [phpinfo](http://www.php.net/phpinfo)()

```
error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE
```

Or do it in the script

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

also consider setting `display_errors = Off` for live websites.

Answer (score 2):

It's not constant, its an associative index. Use quotes:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

**Edit:** If this is on a production environment and you simply need to hide these messages to buy you time to correct the real issue, add this to your page:

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Also it's interesting who is downvote my question, and why? lol

Comment: Whoever the downvoter, they never placed in position where they have to fix somebody else code that created and run in old version of xampp and have thousand of unquotes array in a hundred separates file and should be fixed in an hour while in the same time they have another task to do...

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the configuration to fix your bad coding habits. This is what you should do:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

**not** this

```
$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]
```

You *could* set the error level to ignore warnings, but you might miss some other important warnings if you do that. Just do it the proper way.

Comment: I have a project, where all variables defined without quotes, so i have no time to currect them all right now. It will be better to configure apache server.

Comment: No it would not, Syom. Fix the underlying cause of your bugs. Don't sprinkle on a patch to hide the problem.

Comment: I will fix it latter. But now i have very limited time, so i will hide that notices, until i will correct them. But on older apache versions there are no problems with this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change your `php.ini`, change your code:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

Also that is not called calling a function. [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is an associative array

**Update**

You must be able to add the quotes, suppressing those warnings is a ***very*** bad idea. That warning is basically a message saying "Your code is invalid, but I figured out what you meant soooo... you're lucky!". You won't always be that lucky if you choose not to use quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the boys that wrote PHP decided to change it for the sake of consistency in the PHP internals, ignoring the usability consequences to PHP programmers, and now you have to live with it.  So you face the tough choice of either turning off all notifications or updating all your PHP defines.

PHP4 allowed the definition of unquoted constants and it was no problem.  But I import perfectly good PH4 code to PHP5 and it breaks for no other reason than "you're a bad programmer".

If the authors of PHP wanted to do something truly useful then how about a notice for when a variable that has not been set (i.e. used as an lvalue in an expression) is used.  I've had to deal with hundreds of bugs caused by misspelled variable names being allowed without any warnings from PHP.